# Is there a way to see the requests generated by http-kit?

Tags: clojure, http-kit

I'm working on an application that uses the http-kit client library and I think it's generating requests that have a problem. Since the requests go over https, I can't just sniff them and I also couldn't find a way to make http-kit use a proxy, such as Charles, to see the contents of the packages.

Is there any way to see them? I want to compare them to the same requests in Chrome.

Comment: I've been doing this by tracing the function that calls http-kit, I'm very interested in more efficient ways of working with this.

Answer (score 3):

This actually works with http-kit and it outputs a lot of information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

In short, add this when calling Java to run Clojure:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```